# Can I turn off my PS4 with my Vita using Remote Play?

Tags: ps4, ps-vita, ps-remote-play

I've been using my Vita for Remote Play recently to the point that I haven't turned on my TV for days (go figure). However, despite how much I've been using it, while I know how to turn the PS4 *on* with the Vita, I have no idea how to turn it off. There is a "Button Guide" that you can access by pressing the PS button:

[image: button guide]

The PS button should be self-explanatory, since there isn't an explanation for how it works. However, unlike the way it works on the PS4, holding down the PS button on the Vita only brings up this Vita quick settings menu:

[image: quick settings menu]

Conversely, pressing it doesn't seem to give me the option I'm looking for, either. Is there a way to turn my PS4 back off via Remote Play or do I need to use a controller to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible to turn off your PS4 from your Vita using Remote Play. Instead of holding down the Vita's PS button, you have to press it. When the overlay pops up, you have to *hold your finger on the on-screen PS button labeled "PS4 System"*. This button acts as the PS button on a controller (instead of the Vita's PS button, go figure).

[image: ps4 system button]

Once you've held your finger down on that icon for a full second, the usual PS4 quick menu is displayed and you can turn the PS4 off from there.

[image: ps4 quick menu]